# Add Column Header to the uploader list

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm new with this plugin and I"m just wondering if it's possible to have a column header in the upload file list which is something like this:
[image]

I tried to follow the one mentioned in this [link](https://innovativethought.net/2007/06/11/simulating-a-table-using-an-unordered-list/) and incorporate it with how it is being uploaded using the fine uploader but failed.

Please help me with this guys. Is it possible or not?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my code which I tried to add a header:

```
<ul id="sortableTable" class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
    <li>
        <span><b>No</b></span>
        <span><b>Filename</b></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>1</span>
        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>

        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</button>

        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE 12/5/2017**

I tried what Roysh mentioned that it was possible and this is what I got after loading two files:
[image]

Below is the code which I used. I basically used bootstrap here.

```
<h2>FineUploader</h2>
<div id="UploadFiles"></div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fineuploader") @*This has the declaration of the fineuploader js files*@
<script type="text/template" id="TemplateManualTrigger">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Attach File</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @*This is required*@
        <ul class="list-group qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    No
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    Filename
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Another thing I noticed is that it does not display the header on load. Would appreciate if there's a sample code which I could refer to.

Comment: Do you have any html code? how does this thing get rendered?

Comment: I will edit this

Comment: Ok, so from what I understand, you're trying to add a header to the table? i.e. another tab above the `li` where you have No and Filename?

Comment: Correct. However, I tried to add something on top to make it like a header but it failed.

Comment: Is it possible to have that, or I would need to use one function to be able to accomplish that?

Comment: On it. Will let you know in about an hour

Comment: ok. it is possible. I just need your css to make the adjustments

Comment: Could you share how you did it?

Comment: I need the css to complete it. basically, there are a few ways. 
The easiest is to add another li and set a border on it so it will merge with the table

Comment: @Roysh please check my updated question above.

Comment: I don't really understand what have you been trying to do on the second example you've posted and how did the script tag got there. 
Is there any chance you can post a fiddle?